Are pigs effective intermediate hosts of new viruses, due to being susceptible to human and avian influenza viruses?
I've read the claim that pigs are "melting pot of flu viruses" on a few places on the Internet, some of them not apparently related to veganism or vegetarianism.
For example, Swine influenza A (H1N1) strikes a potential for global disaster, J Emerg Trauma Shock. 2009 May-Aug;2(2):99–105. doi: 10.4103/0974-2700.50744:

Pigs are susceptible to human and avian influenza A viruses; hence, they are believed be effective intermediate hosts for the evolution of new viruses with a potential to produce pandemics. This occurs because the swine serves as a melting pot to generated new hybrid viruses after genetic resortment.

The argument goes that, due to the way pig immune system works, pigs are relatively easily infected by both mammalian flu viruses and bird flu viruses. When a pig is infected by both, those viruses can "mate" by infecting a single cell in that pig and potentially create a new dangerous strain of the flu.
That doesn't make sense to me because the the flu virus is haploid; their genome is a single RNA molecule, so they aren't capable of mating.

You seem to be actually asking two questions - are pigs more susceptible to various flu viruses, and can different viruses "mate" in some way? Genetic recombination (mentioned by a now-deleted comment) provides an answer to the second question.

@RobWatts: Please put your answers into answer boxes, rather than comments that can't be voted on, accepted or edited.

It's not "mating" in any literal sense.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica The virus equivalent of mating (genetically) is when: 1. The virus has multiple gene molecules (be it RNA or DNA). 2. Two related viruses attack the same cell. 3. Gene molecules from different viruses accidentally end up in the same capsid.

@FlatAssembler: Do you have a reference for that claim? I don't think that is considered mating, and calling it that is going to confuse most people.

Yes. The flu is an extremely fast-adapting virus and any host that is capable of being infected by multiple strains at the same time is a high risk source of novel flu strains. Pigs are not the only host which is a risk.
According to Wikipedia:

The central core of the virion contains the viral RNA genome, which is made of eight separate segments

The flu virus consists of 8 separate genome pieces. In the event of co-infection, these viral genome pieces can reassort, so that the resulting flu virions have traits from both the infecting strains. This genomic reassortment is in addition to other mechanisms for recombination.

In addition to the reassortment of these sections, which occurs in flu but few other viruses, it is also possible to get recombination between homologous sections, as can also happen in other viruses (although at lower rates)

This is Skeptics. Where's the evidence to back this all up?

There is a link in the question to a published paper on this very topic that I do not feel the need to duplicate

@CJR: If the OP provides a link that they doubt, it is normally expected to provide a stronger link to support or refute it (unless it is an explanation of how they have misunderstood it).

I do not feel the need to support or refute the source. The question was skeptical because of an obscure aspect of viral genetics that Wikipedia adequately covers. The reference in the question is probably fine although there are much better flu evolution references that could have been chosen.

@Oddthinking Under the circumstances, I think it's reasonable to interpret the question as being caused by uncertainty: unfamiliarity with the field, and /possibly/ not recognising the institution he was citing.

The answer to this is a resounding Yes.
Pigs are the melting pot for influenza and a common intermediate host between influenza viruses that infect birds and influenza viruses infecting humans.
The paper referenced in the question is a very poor example of the literature, it lacks references to ALL of the seminal papers on this topic, which date back to a series of papers titled The "in vivo" production of "new" influenza A viruses." The first of these was The "in vivo" production of "new" influenza A viruses. I. Genetic recombination between avian and mammalian influenza viruses by R.G. Webster, C. H. Campbell and  A. Granoff in 19711.
In this paper, Rob Webster identified that co-infection of influenza viruses caused recombination of the genomes of the viruses in animals, this was followed by two more publications2,3, which covered the isolation of these viruses and transmission conditions for these viruses.
For viruses to infect, they need to bind to cellular chemicals using the virus' own surface proteins. In the case of influenza virus, these proteins are the hemagglutinin (HA) proteins, which bind to various forms of sialated oligosaccharides on the cell surface. The HA forms make up one half of the names of the viruses - the H7 part in H7N3, for instance. The other (N3) part is neuraminidase (NA), which has a different role in release from the cell surface after new virions are generated.
The reason pigs are such a good melting pot is that the forms of sialic acids in their lungs are a mix of those found in birds (predominantly α-2,3 sialation) and humans (predominantly α-2,6 sialation), so the viruses selected for by infection in pigs are capable of infecting both humans and birds. Now, it's not quite as simple as that, as we also have α-2,3 linkages in our respiratory epithelium, but these are largely found in the lower lung, not the epithelia commonly infected during the initial infection, which normally happens in the nasal or tracheal epithelia.
An excellent summary of the biology of influenza viruses written by Nicole Bouuvier and Peter Palese4 is freely available of PubMed Central, which covers in reasonable detail the mechanisms of the influenza virus replication cycle.
Anyway, back to Rob Webster and his papers. The 3rd paper in the series; The "in vivo" production of "new" influenza viruses. 3. Isolation of recombinant influenza viruses under simulated conditions of natural transmission, is the critical one here, which was the first to demonstrate that recombination between viruses from birds and humans can occur under conditions simulating natural transmission. He also produced another paper titled Studies on the origin of pandemic influenza: IV. Selection and transmission of “new” influenza viruses in vivo5 that showed that the recombinant viruses could be stable and form continuous trains of transmission.
References:

Webster RG, Campbell CH, Granoff A. The "in vivo" production of "new" influenza A viruses. I. Genetic recombination between avian and mammalian influenza viruses. Virology. 1971 May;44(2):317-28. doi: 10.1016/0042-6822(71)90263-7. PMID: 5565817.

Webster RG, Campbell CH. The in vivo production of "new" influenza A viruses. II. In vivo isolation of "new" viruses. Virology. 1972 May;48(2):528-36. doi: 10.1016/0042-6822(72)90063-3. PMID: 4112504.

Webster RG, Campbell CH, Granoff A. The "in vivo" production of "new" influenza viruses. 3. Isolation of recombinant influenza viruses under simulated conditions of natural transmission. Virology. 1973 Jan;51(1):149-62. doi: 10.1016/0042-6822(73)90375-9. PMID: 4684582.

Bouvier NM, Palese P. The biology of influenza viruses. Vaccine. 2008 Sep 12;26 Suppl 4(Suppl 4):D49-53. doi: 10.1016/j.vaccine.2008.07.039. PMID: 19230160; PMCID: PMC3074182.

Webster RG, Campbell CH. Studies on the origin of pandemic influenza. IV. Selection and transmission of "new" influenza viruses in vivo. Virology. 1974 Dec;62(2):404-13. doi: 10.1016/0042-6822(74)90402-4. PMID: 4432372.



Pigs are especially good animals to study flu viruses. The first strain that was identified had been cultivated in the pig colony high above the Rockefeller Institute, now Rockefeller University, in New York City.
